# Problem with `:tabnew' command when gVim is maximized under Ubuntu

Tags: vim

My OS is **Ubuntu 9.04**

When I maximize **gVim** windows

And then type command:

```
:tabnew
```

gVim window's height changed.

gVim's **Status-bar** is hidden by Ubuntu's **Task-bar**.

gVim under **Windows XP** works fine.

Is there some solution to handle this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find a proper solution for this? I have the same exact problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens to me as well. The workaround that I use is to minimize gVim then maximize it again. After that the status bar is visible again.

P.S. This question probably belongs on superuser or askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Bug is described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/+bug/137854

Bug is reported fixed in debian, but the issue is still there with Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty)

"unmaximise" and then maximise the window is a workaround the problem.